How can I reduce the spacing between vertical lines (vlines) in Matplotlib?
I'm creating a plot in Matplotlib where I display vertical lines (similar to bars). However, I can't manage to reduce the spacing between these lines. No matter which parameters I change, the lines remain too far apart. Additionally, the lines at the edges of the plot sometimes stick directly to the plot edge or even disappear when scaling.
Here is an image of my current plot:

What I Want to Achieve:
The vertical lines should be closer together so that the spacing between them is smaller.
The lines at the edges of the plot should not stick to the edge or disappear but have the same spacing as the other lines.
What I Have Tried So Far:
Adjusting linewidth, markeredgewidth, and markersize.
Changing figsize and axis limits with plt.xlim() and plt.ylim().
Using plt.tight_layout() and adjusting subplots_adjust().
Researching solutions on the internet over the last two days, but without success.
import pandas as pd
import glob
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.lines as mlines
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches

data = {
    "Variant": [
        "Variant 1: Photovoltaic system", "Variant 1: Photovoltaic system", "Variant 1: Photovoltaic system",
        "Variant 1: Photovoltaic system", "Variant 1: Photovoltaic system", "Variant 2: Onshore wind turbine",
        "Variant 2: Onshore wind turbine", "Variant 2: Onshore wind turbine", "Variant 2: Onshore wind turbine",
        "Variant 2: Onshore wind turbine", "Variant 3: Offshore wind turbine", "Variant 3: Offshore wind turbine",
        "Variant 3: Offshore wind turbine", "Variant 3: Offshore wind turbine", "Variant 3: Offshore wind turbine",
        "Variant 4: Geothermal plant", "Variant 4: Geothermal plant", "Variant 4: Geothermal plant",
        "Variant 4: Geothermal plant", "Variant 4: Geothermal plant"
    ],
    "Type": ["Utility value"] * 20,
    "Person": [
        "Person 1", "Person 2", "Person 3", "Person 4", "Person 5", "Person 1", "Person 2", "Person 3", "Person 4",
        "Person 5", "Person 1", "Person 2", "Person 3", "Person 4", "Person 5", "Person 1", "Person 2", "Person 3",
        "Person 4", "Person 5"
    ],
    "Criterion": ["Overall utility value"] * 20,
    "Rating": [
        370, 510, 470, 625, 750, 475, 605, 500, 665, 790, 710, 600, 715, 575, 700, 370, 350, 100, 585, 100
    ]
}

# Create the DataFrame:
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df_2 = df

# Set colors:
palette = ["#007CAA", "#A8005C", "#AED3E7", "#7B0040", "#00597A", "#55A930", "#D50C2F"]

# Function to insert a line break after the second space:
def split_label(label):
    words = label.split(" ")
    if len(words) <= 2:
        # If the criterion name consists of two or fewer words, make no changes
        return label
    else:
        # First part: the first two words
        first_part = " ".join(words[:2])
        # Second part: the rest of the criterion name
        second_part = " ".join(words[2:])
        # Combine the parts with a line break
        return first_part + "\n" + second_part

# Split criterion names after every second space:
df_2["Variant"] = df_2["Variant"].apply(split_label)

# Create a list of criteria and exclude "Overall utility value":
criteria_2 = df_2["Variant"].unique().tolist()

# Mapping between criteria and colors:
color_mapping_2 = dict(zip(criteria_2, palette))

# Overall utility value:
# Filter by specific conditions:
other_data_all = df_2[
    (df_2["Type"] == "Utility value") &
    (df_2["Person"] != "Person 1") &
    (df_2["Criterion"] == "Overall utility value")
]

own_data_all = df_2[
    (df_2["Type"] == "Utility value") &
    (df_2["Person"] == "Person 1") &
    (df_2["Criterion"] == "Overall utility value")
]

# Group by criterion and calculate min and max:
other_grouped_data_all = other_data_all.groupby("Variant")["Evaluation"].agg(["min", "max"]).reset_index()

# Ensure "grouped" contains the criteria in the same order as "criteria_2":
other_grouped_data_all = other_grouped_data_all.set_index("Variant").loc[criteria_2].reset_index()

# Assign colors to the vertical lines based on the criteria:
line_colors_all = other_grouped_data_all["Variant"].map(color_mapping_2).tolist()

# Create the plot:
plt.figure(figsize=(16, 7))

# Set Y-axis limits:
y_limits_all = []
y_limits_all.append(other_grouped_data_all["min"].min())
y_limits_all.append(other_grouped_data_all["max"].max())
y_limits_all.append(own_data_all["Evaluation"].min())
y_limits_all.append(own_data_all["Evaluation"].max())
plt.ylim(min(y_limits_all) - 0.1 * min(y_limits_all), max(y_limits_all) + 0.1 * max(y_limits_all))

# Scatter plot for Samuel's ratings:
plt.scatter(
    own_data_all["Variant"],
    own_data_all["Evaluation"],
    color="#FFCC00",
    s=500,
    label="Person 1",
    zorder=3
)

# Display text to the right of the points:
for x, y in zip(own_data_all["Variant"], own_data_all["Evaluation"]):
    plt.text(
        x,
        y,
        f"{y:.2f}",
        fontsize=15,
        ha="left",
        va="center",
        color="#FFCC00",
        transform=plt.gca().transData + matplotlib.transforms.ScaledTranslation(15 / 72, 0, plt.gcf().dpi_scale_trans),
        # Background color:
        bbox=dict(
            facecolor="darkgrey",
            edgecolor="none",
            boxstyle="round, pad=0.1"
        )
    )

# Vertical lines for the rating range of other people:
plt.vlines(
    x=other_grouped_data_all["Variant"],
    ymin=other_grouped_data_all["min"],
    ymax=other_grouped_data_all["max"],
    colors=palette,
    linewidth=80,
    label="Other people",
    zorder=2
)

# Display text for min/max values above/below the bars:
for x, ymin, ymax in zip(other_grouped_data_all["Variant"], other_grouped_data_all["min"], other_grouped_data_all["max"]):
    # Max value:
    plt.text(
        x,
        ymax + 0.2,
        f"{ymax:.2f}",
        fontsize=15, 
        ha="center",
        va="bottom"
    )

    # Min value:
    plt.text(
        x,
        ymin - 0.2,
        f"{ymin:.2f}",
        fontsize=15,
        ha="center",
        va="top"
    )

# Add title and axis labels:
plt.title("Overall Utility Value per Variant", fontsize=25)
plt.xlabel("Variant", fontsize=25)
plt.ylabel("Rating", fontsize=25)

# Create custom legend entries:
scatter_handle = mlines.Line2D([], [], color="#FFCC00", marker="o", linestyle="None", markersize=8, label="Person 1")
vline_handle = mlines.Line2D([], [], color="#A8005C", marker="|", linestyle="None", markersize=18, markeredgewidth=13, label="Other People")

# Add legend with custom handles:
plt.legend(handles=[scatter_handle, vline_handle], fontsize=8)

# Axis adjustments and grid:
plt.xticks(fontsize=18)
plt.grid(axis="y", linestyle="--", alpha=0.7)
plt.show()


It seems like you basically want a bar chart.  Why not use bar?  You can set the bottom parameter to the y minimums https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.bar.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.bar

One way to do this is to introduce a specing factor:
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.lines as mlines
import matplotlib.transforms

data = {
    "Variant": [
        "Variant 1: Photovoltaic system", "Variant 1: Photovoltaic system", "Variant 1: Photovoltaic system",
        "Variant 1: Photovoltaic system", "Variant 1: Photovoltaic system", "Variant 2: Onshore wind turbine",
        "Variant 2: Onshore wind turbine", "Variant 2: Onshore wind turbine", "Variant 2: Onshore wind turbine",
        "Variant 2: Onshore wind turbine", "Variant 3: Offshore wind turbine", "Variant 3: Offshore wind turbine",
        "Variant 3: Offshore wind turbine", "Variant 3: Offshore wind turbine", "Variant 3: Offshore wind turbine",
        "Variant 4: Geothermal plant", "Variant 4: Geothermal plant", "Variant 4: Geothermal plant",
        "Variant 4: Geothermal plant", "Variant 4: Geothermal plant"
    ],
    "Type": ["Utility value"] * 20,
    "Person": [
        "Person 1", "Person 2", "Person 3", "Person 4", "Person 5", "Person 1", "Person 2", "Person 3", "Person 4",
        "Person 5", "Person 1", "Person 2", "Person 3", "Person 4", "Person 5", "Person 1", "Person 2", "Person 3",
        "Person 4", "Person 5"
    ],
    "Criterion": ["Overall utility value"] * 20,
    "Evaluation": [
        370, 510, 470, 625, 750, 475, 605, 500, 665, 790, 710, 600, 715, 575, 700, 370, 350, 100, 585, 100
    ]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

palette = ["#007CAA", "#A8005C", "#AED3E7", "#7B0040", "#00597A", "#55A930", "#D50C2F"]

def split_label(label):
    words = label.split(" ")
    if len(words) <= 2:
        return label
    else:
        first_part = " ".join(words[:2])
        second_part = " ".join(words[2:])
        return first_part + "\n" + second_part

df["Variant"] = df["Variant"].apply(split_label)

criteria = df["Variant"].unique().tolist()
color_mapping = dict(zip(criteria, palette))

other_data = df[
    (df["Type"] == "Utility value") & 
    (df["Person"] != "Person 1") & 
    (df["Criterion"] == "Overall utility value")
]

own_data = df[
    (df["Type"] == "Utility value") & 
    (df["Person"] == "Person 1") & 
    (df["Criterion"] == "Overall utility value")
]

other_grouped_data = other_data.groupby("Variant")["Evaluation"].agg(["min", "max"]).reset_index()
other_grouped_data = other_grouped_data.set_index("Variant").loc[criteria].reset_index()
line_colors = other_grouped_data["Variant"].map(color_mapping).tolist()

categories = other_grouped_data["Variant"]
x_positions = range(len(categories))

spacing_factor = 1.6
x_positions = [i * spacing_factor for i in range(len(categories))]

plt.figure(figsize=(16, 7))

plt.scatter(
    x_positions,
    own_data["Evaluation"],
    color="#FFCC00",
    s=500,
    label="Person 1",
    zorder=3
)

for x, y in zip(x_positions, own_data["Evaluation"]):
    plt.text(
        x,
        y,
        f"{y:.2f}",
        fontsize=15,
        ha="left",
        va="center",
        color="#FFCC00",
        transform=plt.gca().transData + matplotlib.transforms.ScaledTranslation(15 / 72, 0, plt.gcf().dpi_scale_trans),
        bbox=dict(facecolor="darkgrey", edgecolor="none", boxstyle="round, pad=0.1")
    )

plt.vlines(
    x=x_positions,
    ymin=other_grouped_data["min"],
    ymax=other_grouped_data["max"],
    colors=palette,
    linewidth=80,
    label="Other People",
    zorder=2
)

for x, ymin, ymax in zip(x_positions, other_grouped_data["min"], other_grouped_data["max"]):
    plt.text(
        x,
        ymax + 0.2,
        f"{ymax:.2f}",
        fontsize=15,
        ha="center",
        va="bottom"
    )
    plt.text(
        x,
        ymin - 0.2,
        f"{ymin:.2f}",
        fontsize=15,
        ha="center",
        va="top"
    )

plt.xlim(min(x_positions) - spacing_factor, max(x_positions) + spacing_factor)
plt.xticks(ticks=x_positions, labels=categories, fontsize=18)
plt.title("Overall Utility Value per Variant", fontsize=25)
plt.xlabel("Variant", fontsize=25)
plt.ylabel("Rating", fontsize=25)

scatter_handle = mlines.Line2D([], [], color="#FFCC00", marker="o", linestyle="None", markersize=8, label="Person 1")
vline_handle = mlines.Line2D([], [], color="#A8005C", marker="|", linestyle="None", markersize=18, markeredgewidth=13, label="Other People")
plt.legend(handles=[scatter_handle, vline_handle], fontsize=15)

plt.grid(axis="y", linestyle="--", alpha=0.7)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()

which gives

